# How to solve an out of bounds exception error?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, bounds, out

I posted a question yesterday about some code I was writing and was having trouble making a class implement an interface correctly. Thanks to the great help of users on here that has been fixed, and so I thought I could possibly get help again.

I am now having trouble with an out of bounds exception error and, for the life of me, I can't see what the problem is, though I am quite new to java.

The application displays piano keys which allow the user to click on them, and it saves the order they were clicked and the midicode of the notes for the specific sound. Then when the user clicks play, it recalls the tune in the order the notes were saved. I am using an array list to store the notes and then want to recall them when the user clicks play, which calls the "start" method and then repeatedly calls a "getNextNote" method until there are no more notes. However, whenever I click play I get an out of bounds exception error. Below is my code so far;

```
import java.util.*;
import mvcchords.*;

public class MyNoteStore implements NoteStore {

public ArrayList<Integer> Notes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int k;

public void noteAdded(int midicode) {
    Notes.add(midicode);
}

public boolean hasNextNote() {
    if(Notes.get(k) != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public int getNextNote() {

        if(hasNextNote() == true)
            return Notes.get(k);
        else
            return 0;
    }

public void start(int sortOrder) {

    for(k = 0; k < Notes.size(); k++){
    hasNextNote();
    getNextNote();
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the error I get when I try and click play with 3 notes stored (though the error is the same no matter how many notes I have stored, just with the numbers at the end equal to how many notes I have selected):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
```

Any help with this would be great, thank you in advance :)

I will also do my best to provide any extra information required :)

EDIT: Changed the for loop to

```
 for(k = 0; k < Notes.size(); k++)
```

And the same error still occurs :(

Comment: Regarding the EDIT: The code shown here is now working (please note that I don't say it is correct). If you still get the error then either you are not executing the code you think or another IndexOutOfBounds happens in some piece of code which you have not shown us. So compare the stacktraces of the original error with the new error and see if it is really the same error.

Comment: Ah you are correct, after checking the error it is now pointing at "if(Notes.get(k) != null)" in the hasNextNote method instead of the for loop. Though now I do not see my error in this! Thank you for pointing that out though!

Comment: Let me guess: that `hasNextNote` is not the call from `start` (either directly or with the intermediate `getNextNote`) but from another place? In that case the value of `k` is unpredictable.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean? (Sorry I am quite a novice, I must come across very annoying!). When 'start' is called, it executes 'hasNextNote' and 'getNextNote'. 'k' should just increment until 'hasNextNote' returns false, meaning there are no more notes.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking vs. <= size(), instead of < size(), which means if size is 2, you'll look up index 2 (while the valid indicies are 0 and 1).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately I still get the exact same error even with this change :(

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with code below:

```
public class MyNoteStore implements NoteStore {

private List<Integer> notes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void noteAdded(int midicode) {
    notes.add(midicode);
}

public boolean hasNextNote() {
   // do you need this method?
}

public int getNextNote() {
   // do you need this method?
}
public void start(int sortOrder) {
    for(Integer note : notes){
       // "note" var contains each note from notes
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using an interface that has been given to me which I cannot edit so I have to retain all the methods from that :( Thank you for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

You read one item too much from your collection:

```
for(k = 0; k <= Notes.size(); k++) ...
```

The comparison should read `k < Notes.size();` instead. The collection is 0-indexed and therefore the last entry has index `size-1` and not `size`.